# iOS CallKit Outgoing Call Don't Support Holding

Tags: objective-c, callkit

When I have an incoming call, I can set `supportsHolding` to `NO` in `CXCallUpdate`.

But how can I do the same in an outgoing call?

My goal is that if a new GSM call wants to interrupt, make iOS don't show the option to hold this call, only hanging up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.

A CXCallUpdate can be sent to the outgoing call also.

I report the update in the `completion` block of `requestTransaction`:

```
[callController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError* _Nullable error) {
    if (error) NSLog(@"iOS Call Start Error: %@", error);
    else
    {
        CXCallUpdate* update = [CXCallUpdate new];
        update.supportsHolding = NO;
        [provider reportCallWithUUID:uuid updated:update];
    }
}];
```